# Why does nobody use indentation in css?

Tags: coding-style, css, indentation

I find css quite hard to read sometimes. Indents, depending on the dom structure, would greatly increase readability. Consider the following example:

```
#page {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
    #page p {
        white-space:nowrap;
    } #page p:hover {
            display:inline-block;
    }
    #page .myclass {
        text-align:left;
    }
        #page .myclass a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
#footer {
    display:none;
}
```

Simple question: Why is nobody using intends in any way near to this? Even phpstorm does not support such indents by default: I have to navigate with <kbd>-></kbd> and <kbd>del</kbd> inconveniently.

It seems that by convention, all css selectors have to start at the leftmost indent. This doesn't make sense to me, since I have literally never seen a stylesheet which even reached the rightmost edge of my monitor. Typical css sheet below.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Indentation, in my experience, should match syntax, not semantics. By indenting further, many coders might briefly think that it's somehow part of the same syntactical rule that was above, decreasing code readability even if it's meant to improve semantic readability. LESS, a CSS transpiler, happens to make this easier by actually providing special *syntax* for the above situation, in which the first curly brace does not close.

Comment: There css preprocessors that support *nesting*, which is similar to what you want, but without being as ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one is doing that because it does not make sense from a syntactical perspective. While it conceptually makes sense to indent items that have a child relationship with a parent item, it does not work well in practice for CSS.

Keep in mind that there is a distinction between DOM nodes and CSS selectors. Although elements may be nested within each other in the DOM, selectors are not nested within each other. In your example, `#page p` is actually not a child of `#page`; they refer to two distinct paths within the DOM.